# Maven+ReportNG+Jenkins+Command Line

Tags: maven, jenkins, reportng

I would like to know how can I run a test built with maven to generate the report and then convert the report to ReportNG format using the command line.

To after that insert the report on Jenkins using the plugin HTML Reporter from Jenkins.

I want to do this because I am getting error when I put the listeners on test.

I am using this to execute the test by Jenkins:

```
    mvn test (after using "mvn clean install" on first time)
```

I try use mvn install but I am getting the same error

Thanks

EDIT: So I finally manage to fix my POM file, the problem has some plugins that aren't specified like velocity, reportng and guice. Anyway I will left here my POM fixed so it can help someone else =)

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>selenium.simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-simple</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>selenium-simple</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.8.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>2.24.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
                <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
                <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>velocity</groupId>
                <artifactId>velocity-dep</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>                
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- specify UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or any other file encoding -->
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <webdriver.ie.driver>src/main/resources/drivers/internetexplorer/iedriverserver_2.24.1_x64.exe</webdriver.ie.driver>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: How about posting the relevant parts of `pom.xml`?

Comment: POM file added to post

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message:

> Some problems were encountered while building the effective model
>   forselenium.simple:selenium-simple:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>       [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ line 43,
>   column 12

You should pin the version for maven-surefire-plugin like the following:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.17</version>
       ...
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
..
</build>
```

If don't do this as you you will use an old version (maven-surefire-plugin:2.10) which might be too old. I assume that after you put the version into your pom the problems with the listener will be gone.

BTW: Why not using up-to-date versions of maven-resources-plugin (2.6) and testng (6.8.7)..

Comment: The first lines of warning has disapear wich is good, I only change the version from 2.17 to 2.10

I am using these version because is the versions client want to use...

Comment: If you stuck with an old version this might cause your problem. I would suggest to test with newer version if it works.

Comment: I update all versions you suggest, maven-resources-plugin & testng, but I am still getting the same errors

Comment: Based on your changes it does not look like: `maven-surefire-plugin:<version>2.10</version>`

Comment: After the change the code don't compile. This is why I stick with 2.10 on first place...

I change the error and POM code.

Comment: If you change maven-surefire-plugin version your code does not compile? Than something else is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56639/discussion-between-user3746280-and-khmarbaise).